# Building a collapsable nav bar inside a custom navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, web-frontend

I have a following small custom navbar (Meaning I don't have any navbar bootstrap classes in it as shown in code), my question is that is there any way I can make a left side collapsable navbar in it (As shown in wireframe below) Code snippet is as follows:

```
<div class="topnav" role="navigation">
  <a class="active" href="#" > Home </a>
  <a href="#"> About </a>
  <a href="#"> Contact </a>
  <form action="#">
    <div class="search-container">
  <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Search..">
  <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"> </i></button>
</form>
</div>
</div>
<br> <br>
```

[wireframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vPBy.jpg)

Comment: When you have something custom like this you need to include all of the relevant code to make sure it can actually be tested i.e. reproduce the navbar the same way as you have it now. The current code snippet doesn't allow to do that.

Comment: If I understand correct, you have to use the toggler  > https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#toggler